# Streaming Analytics Query Error

Tags: cortana-intelligence, azure-stream-analytics

When typing my query for Streaming Analytics I don't receive any error messages, however, when I start my streaming analytics job, I receive the following error:

Stream Analytics job has validation errors: The output dsleads used in the query was not defined. Activity Id: '5cc961c5-4dbd-4a63-95df-8e3b08d2121c-2016-03-28 14:56:21Z'.

I've checked the output name and have verified that it's correct. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The query I'm using is as follows:

SELECT type, count(*) as count, system.timestamp as time
INTO dsleads
FROM ttvhuball timestamp by time
GROUP BY type, TumblingWindow(minute, 10)

I've scoured the internet and have not found anything helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the incorrect output name. One needs to specify the output name. I was specifying the dataset name of the output I needed to specify.

Comment: Glad you solved it! Can you click the checkmark by your answer so people know this is resolved and for future searches?

Comment: I will in 2 days. It says I can't click my own answer until 2 days later.

Answer (score 1):

seems like an output alias error. Is the output sink alias that you've created(that is you give a name to it during creation) "dsleads" in your case?

Also worth mentioning INTO is the output and FROM is the input. INTO always needs to come before FROM in the query as well.

Hope this helps!

Mert